# Font Showing "Double" When Viewed on Mobile Browser

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm having an issue when using the typeface "Abril Fatface" in that it's displaying correctly at larger sizes and on web browsers, however when viewed at smaller sizes on handheld devices it has a "double image" effect on the thin arms and spurs. The font size is set to 48px.

I have attached a photo that shows what I am referencing below. It is particularly noticeable on the: "W" "e" "g" "a" "t" "m" "c" "r" etc. This screenshot is from Chrome on an iPhone 8, however I have tried this on the same phone in Safari and in Chrome on an iPhone 5 and the issue is still there.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? I honestly have no idea what to search for, so I apologize if this is a common issue.

[image]

Comment: [I can't seem to reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/uov59waq/). Do you see the problem on that link? Does it seem to be device- and/or browser-dependent?

Comment: @showdev cannot reproduce it as well.

Comment: @showdev Well that is bizarre. It doesn't seem to be showing up the same when viewing your jsfiddle link on the same phone in the same browser.. Is there any snipets of my code you would like me to show that may help? FYI: link to website is http://adprint.co.nz/test

Comment: Not seeing this on Chrome for android.

Comment: The `font-weight` for `h1` in your code is computed to `700`, but that font's natural setting is 400 - so the browser is increasing the weight. Perhaps on IOS this is causing the issue?

Comment: @sol that solves it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

to your `<head>` section.